# limits.conf not working for SSH connections on Fedora 33

Tags: fedora, limit, administration

I am trying to set a limit on a group called `rlimited`. I have the following in my `/etc/security/limits.conf`

```
@rlimited hard cpu 5
```

The same file exists in the `/etc/security/limits.d/` folder.

I've also modified my `/etc/pam.d/sshd` and `/etc/pam.d/login` files to include the line

```
session required pam_limits.so
```

However, new SSH connections do not have this five minute CPU time limit displayed when running `ulimit -a`.

I am running Fedora 33. Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

You have to set also **soft** limit because it's the one that will affect the processes.
**hard** limit defines only the limit for soft limits.

You can do :

```
@rlimited hard cpu 5
@rlimited soft cpu 5
```

OR ( For both soft and hard ) :

```
@rlimited - cpu 5
```

Also check the configuration files set under `/etc/security/limits.d/` ; It's possible that the main configuration is overridden.

Comment: Hi Reda, unfortunately this does not seem to solve the issue. I am still getting `unlimited` as the output after running `ulimit -t` on a new SSH shell

Comment: you have to run `ulimit -t` as one of the users in `rlimited`  group and relogin.

Comment: As I mentioned in my prior comment I ran `ulimit -t` on a new SSH session. I also did this with a user in the `rlimited` group and it still didn’t work.

Comment: check if there is any configurauon under /etc/security/limits.d  ; also try setting cpu within command line and check if the value  changed without relogin